# My task is not in the right category, but always in the first one

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, categories

I come here because I have a To Do List application on rails, and when I add a task, it does not go in the correct category, but always the first one! I searched but cannot find.

Here is my code:

index.html.erb :

```html
<h1 class="text-center mb-4">Welcome to my todolist app</h1>
<%= render 'layouts/task_form'  %>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
  <% @categories.each do  |category|%>
  <li><%= category.title  %></li>
  <div class="card">
    <ul>
      <% category.tasks.each do |task|  %>
      <li  id="task-list">
        <%= task.title  %>
        <% unless task.deadline.nil? %>
          , to read: <%= task.deadline.strftime('%D')  %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% @tasks.each do |task|  %>
      <div class="card col-3">
        <% unless task.image.nil? %>
          <%= image_tag task.image, class: "rounded-circle" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

create.js.erb :

```js
document.getElementById("task-list").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<%= j render 'task', task: @task %>")
```

Comment: Because element ids must be unique by definition. `getElementById()` will return the first if there are more than one in page

Comment: oh okay I see, i thought the category was already selected, but how to select it, i guess it's through the create.js.erb?

Comment: Ya, you need to change this line `<li  id="task-list">` so the id is unique in each iteration of the loop.  One way could be to just add the `id` to it `<li  id="task-list-<%= task.id %>">` and then you would have to get that in the code where you are grabbing the element somehow `document.getElementById("task-list-" + elId )`

Comment: You should really use a HTML validator.  `<div class="card">` is invalid as the children of a `<ul>` element should be `<li>` tags.